# How properly dynamically allocate 2d array inside void function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I 'm still newbie in C++, so don't be mean to me. I would like to know how to initialize 2 dimentional array in the void function.

This is my example code but it gives me exceptions about access violation locations instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void matrixInit(char***);
void matrixDel(char**);

void main(void){
    char** game=0;
    matrixInit(&game);
    matrixDel(game);
    return;
}


void matrixInit(char*** matrix) {
    matrix = new char**[3];
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new char*[3];
        for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            *matrix[i][j] = '0';
    }
    return;
}

void matrixDel(char** matrix) {
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] *matrix;
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you're programming in C++, why not pass the pointer by reference? Or use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Or better yet, since you have fixed sizes then just use normal arrays or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: You have 2 choices. Leak memory like a sieve and spend hours debugging mysterious overruns, or use standard containers.

Comment: Might you explain the first method? I don't want to use vectors and sizes are fixed just in an example, but in a real case the sizes will be unknown

Comment: If you go one pointer/address at a time when writing pointer to pointers, you can write clean code and understand what you're doing. It's not difficult, takes some practice. No need to waste time with a debugger.

Comment: `return;` in last statement is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props to *@fireant* for the help with allocating the array. After some research and debugger plays, I figure all it out. I hope this solution will help someone in the future!

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int** matrixInit(int, int);
void matrixInit(int***, int, int);
void matrixDel(int**, int);
void matrixFill(int**, int, int);
void matrixPrint(int**, int, int);


void main(void) {
    const int rows = 3, cols = 3;
    int** game;

    matrixInit(&game, rows, cols); //Void allocation
    //game = matrixInit(rows, cols);  //Alternative allocation

    matrixFill(game, rows, cols);
    matrixPrint(game, rows, cols);
    matrixDel(game, rows);
    cout << endl << "Passed!"; //<iostream> lib required
    _getch(); //<conio.h> lib required
    return;
}


//Dynamical array allocation void function
void matrixInit(int*** matrix, int nRow, int nColumn) {
    (*matrix) = new int*[nRow];
    for (int i(0); i < nRow; i++)
        (*matrix)[i] = new int[nColumn];
}


//Dynamical array allocation pointer return function
int** matrixInit(int nRow, int nColumn) {
    int** matrix = new int*[nRow];
    for (int i(0); i < nRow; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[nColumn];

    return matrix;
}


//Dynamical array deallocation void function
void matrixDel(int** matrix, int nRow) {
    for (int i(0); i < nRow; i++)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;
}


//Fill array void function 
void matrixFill(int** matrix, int nRow, int nColumn) {
    for (int i(0); i < nRow; i++)
        for (int j(0); j < nColumn; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = (j + 1) + (i * nRow);
}


//Print array void function
void matrixPrint(int** matrix, int nRow, int nColumn) {
    for (int i(0); i < nRow; i++)
        for (int j(0); j < nColumn; j++)
            cout << "[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " << matrix[i][j] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there,

```
void matrixInit(char*** matrix) {
    (*matrix) = new char*[3];
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++) {
        (*matrix)[i] = new char[3];
        for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            (*matrix)[i][j] = '0';
    }
    return;
}
```

You're passing the address `matrixInit(&game)`, but `matrix = new char**[3];` is overwriting the passed address. Thus, `game` in `main` is not pointing to the allocated memory. You could have written `void matrixInit(char*** const matrix)` to make sure you don't change the address accidentally inside the function. As a practice try to fix your delete function.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know that at least one programmer who is really good at programming and answers the questions like this. Gonna try fix delete function :D